# WPF Crop and resize an image without losing original image

Tags: wpf

I am trying to create a WPF control which crops and re-sizes an image via adorners without losing the original image ie once cropped it should be possible to get back the original by reversing the steps and the cropped image should also be resizeable.

Can't seem to come up with a viable solution.

Any bright ideas? Just need a general approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this helps

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/CropAdorner.aspx

http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/08/image-manipulation-using-wpf-imaging-classes/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2007/11/11/bigger-isn-t-always-better-how-to-resize-images-without-reloading-them-with-wpf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

check out

[Interactive WPF image cropper control](http://teamdistinction.com/labs/interactive-wpf-image-cropper-control/)

you can download the source. should thank teamdistinction.

Comment: Cropping control is trivial. I need a combined cropping and resizing control.