# Showing part of image in display area of WPF image control using ScaleTransform and TranslateTransform

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `WPF` `Image` control already working in my application. Using `ScaleTransform` and `TranslateTransform`, the `Image` control has zooming and panning functionality working very well.

I was wondering if there is any way to display certain rectangle area of the image source in the `Image` control using `ScaleTransform` and `TranslateTransform`. In order to do that, I think I need to get/set rectangle coordinates of the image source in view port of the `Image` control. But it seems that I can't find any reference on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucky for me, the rectangles have all the same size so I could find easily a fixed scale value for ScaleTrensformation such as 5.0 which will fit each rectangle into the view port. Once that determined, I could come up with following function to calculate values for TranslateTransform in terms of coordinate in the image. Hope it may help people in a similar situation.

```
    public void SetImageCoordinate(double x, double y)
    {

        TransformGroup transformGroup = (TransformGroup)image.RenderTransform;
        ScaleTransform transform = (ScaleTransform)transformGroup.Children[0];

        ImageSource imageSource = image.Source;
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = (BitmapImage) imageSource ;
        //Now since you got the image displayed in Image control. You can easily map the mouse position to the Pixel scale.

        var pixelMousePositionX = -(x ) / bitmapImage.PixelWidth * transform.ScaleX * image.ActualWidth;
        var pixelMousePositionY = -(y) / bitmapImage.PixelHeight * transform.ScaleY * image.ActualHeight;

        //MessageBox.Show("X: " + pixelMousePositionX + "; Y: " + pixelMousePositionY);

        var tt = (TranslateTransform)((TransformGroup)image.RenderTransform).Children.First(tr => tr is TranslateTransform);
        tt.X = pixelMousePositionX;
        tt.Y = pixelMousePositionY;            
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think [CroppedBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.croppedbitmap.aspx) can help you:

```
<CroppedBitmap x:Key="croppedImage" 
      Source="{StaticResource masterImage}" SourceRect="30 20 105 50"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But then don't I have to throw away zooming and panning functionality? I'd like to keep the huge file so user can move to the other part with zoom and pan.

Comment: @Thomas Check this, maybe help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20245/WPF-Interactive-Image-Cropping-Control or http://stackoverflow.com/a/4551514/440030